# Как реализовать отступы в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Написал приложение и хочу чтобы все логины были на одном уровне. Далее идёт фрагмент кода для создания кнопки

```
newButton.setText(f"   Сайт:  {line[0]:<{self.max_site_len}} Логин:  {line[1]:<{self.max_login_len}}")
```

где `self.max_site_len` и `self.max_login_len` означают максимальную длину сайта и логина соответственно (их длина не превышает 58)

Как есть

[image: Его интерфейс]

И как хочу

[image: Как хочу]

Comment: Либо использовать моноширинный шрифт, либо использовать таблицу вместо кучи кнопок.

Comment: Если совет от @insolor вам не понятен или не подходит -  предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.